# downloading files to a NAS from another machine

Tags: command-line

I have used DockStarter to set up my `sonarr`, `radarr`, `nzbget`, etc in docker on an Ubuntu partition on my laptop but I want to store my downloads on NAS from which I run the Plex server.

I have tried the fstab mount routine to mount my NAS folders onto the docker download directories but I get an error

```
bad option; for several filesystems
```

How would I do this?

Comment: [You need to tell us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/451602/edit) what you mean by "_the fstab mount routine_". You need to tell us what type of filesystems you're getting the error "_bad option; for several filesystems_" from. (I must say that this isn't an error message I've ever encountered before. Are you sure that's _exactly_ what it says?) To help yourself you should look in the man pages to find out which options are permitted for the filesystems in question (`man mount` is a good starting point).